# Rails 6 - Nested Field Not visible in Devise registration/new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've been looking for 2 days and have sound many threads about this problem, all with different answers. I have a Users (devise) table and a Stats table. When a user signs up, I would like to pass a value to the stats table. I hope to accomplish this via hidden field once its working but at current, I cannot get the field to show in devise sign-up. I have generated a sessions/new controller via devise and modified it as such:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource/sign_up    
  def new
    super do |user|
      user.build_stat
    end
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
     super
     @user = current_user.stats.new user_params
     @user.stats.first.user_id = current_user.id
   end
```

My **Users Controller** looks like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all.order(:first_name)
  end

  def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_stat
  
    def edit
      @user = current_user
  end

  def update
      respond_to do |format|
          if current_user.update(user_params)
              format.html { redirect_to current_user, notice: 'You successfully updated your profile.' }
          else 
              format.html { render :edit }
          end
      end
  end

  def delete_image
    image = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:image_id])
    if current_user == image.record
      image.purge
      redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
    else
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Action not allowed"
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :bio,
      :first_name,
      :last_name,
      :profile_picture,
      :runner,
      :ambasador,
      :posterior,
      stats_attributes: [:burpee],
    )
  end
end
```

**model/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
 
  has_many :journals
  has_many :stats

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stats

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  
  has_one_attached :profile_picture, dependent: :destroy
  validates :profile_picture, content_type: [:png, :jpg, :jpeg]
  validates_associated :stats

    def full_name
      "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
    end
end
```

**model/stats.rb**

```
class Stat < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

and my **view**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
          <%= bootstrap_devise_error_messages! %>
      <!-- form stuff here -->

   <%= f.fields_for :stats do |p| %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= p.label :burpee %>
              <%= p.text_field :burpee, class: "form-control" %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
```

And lastly, updated my **Routes.rb** to use the new controller

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :stats
  resources :journals
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions'
  }
```

Where am I going wrong? I've read the devise documentation on setting up custom controllers, I've read countless threads and still I cannot find a solution.

Comment: So is the field you want to add called `burpee` and stored in the Stats table? And you expect the Stat record to be built when a new User is created via a `build_stat` method? Can you add the code and location for `build_stat` because that's kind of important? Also, at a higher level, do you have to generate this field before the user is registed, store it in the form and then process later, or could you generate it in the controller as the user is actually created?

Comment: Yes - basically when a user signs up, I would like to create a row in my stats table once the user is created. `build_stat` came from an answer in another question. 

`Another way in order not to put building resource in the view is to rewrite the devise controller and to be exact, the new method, all u need to do is to change it to:

 def new
   build_resource({})
   resource.build_profile 
   respond_with self.resource
 end`

Comment: Sure, but do you need to create it *before* the user is actually created? That is, part of your problem right now is that you are (I think) building a Stat record based on a blank User record, putting these blank records into a form, and then saving it all once the form is submitted. Is there a reason you can't build a simple form with just a new User record, and then create the Stat record once you actually save the User?

Comment: No, there is no reason it has to be saved before the user is created. My purpose is that in the stats table, I want a row created with default values once a user signs up. I believed that using a nested input would accomplish this but now I'm unsure. Perhaps there is a cleaner or simpler way to accomplish this.

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding the nested form completely and just created the Stat record in your `create` method instead of in the `new` method. The `create` method runs to actually save the record and is generally where logic like this is best located IME. (Also note that you seem to be running `build_stat` twice: once in the `Users::RegistrationsController` controller and once in the `UsersController`. You should probably only do it once!)

Comment: Thanks for your help. As you can tell I'm very novice and trying to hack my way though this. I'll try to figure out how to do this in my controller.

Comment: No problem - it's hard to know how to put things together as you get started. Generally, I'd suggest reading quite a bit of the [Ruby Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and following conventions as much as possible. But we're always here to help on SO when you have a problem!

Comment: @JohnP I was looking through Ruby Guides and google and I can't seem to find an example of how to write that into my controller. Do you have any advice on that?

Comment: It's a bit hard without knowing what the Stat model actually does but you need to look at the `create` method in your RegistrationsController. Currently this creates Stats and assigns them to the `@user` variable, which seems misleading at best. It's almost certainly unnecessary to do the `@user.stats.first.user_id = current_user.id` because Stats `belongs_to` User and so will automatically have its `user_id` field set when you create it (especially if you do as you have here and use `current_user.stats.new`, which tells Rails exactly which User to use).

Comment: ...You may be best off not worrying about Stats until you're more comfortable with Rails in general: one step as a time is often the best way!